High-order derivatives of nominal multivariable function
Say I have a multivariable function $f(x,y,z)$ and $x,y,z$ are all dependent on parameter $b$, i.e
$$
x=x(b),\quad y=y(b),\quad z=z(b).
$$
If I wanna calculate the first-order derivative $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial b}$, it's easy to obtain
$$
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial b} = \nabla f \cdot \dfrac{d\vec{r}}{db},
$$
where $\dfrac{d\vec{r}}{db} = [\dfrac{dx}{db}, \dfrac{dy}{db}, \dfrac{dz}{db}]$. Can I generalize the conclusion for higher-order derivative and obtain
$$
\dfrac{\partial^{k} f}{\partial b^k} = \nabla f \cdot \dfrac{d\vec{r}}{db},
$$
or something similar?

Google is your friend for such a generic question

No, it's more complicated.  You might want to look up Chain Rule
